# I'd like to make an automated response with more than one line

Tags: node.js, discord.js, bots

So I'm doing an automated response command but I need to to respond with more than one line.
(I use node.js/discord.js? and I'm coding a Discord bot)
Can somebody let me know what I would need to do make it more than one line? The following is what I have at the moment.

```
      client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.content === '<response trigger>') {
    msg.channel.send('<Where the response would go>');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating multiline response with discord.js is completely unrelated to the library itself. You simply have to specify a string with a line break.

One possibility to start a new line is by inserting `\n` into your string. There are also other possibilities to do this, just take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6220539/7179628).

In your case a multiline response could look like this:

```js
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === '<response trigger>') {
    msg.channel.send('line1\nline2');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It works just as intended now.

Comment: could you mark my answer as a correct solution?

Comment: Yep! Sorry, I'm new to this platform.